# Direct file upload in django without caching the file

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I was trying to build a django powered file uploader which will upload and store the file directly to the destination location, without caching the file in any temporary location. So far what I understood is, we should write a custom `FileUploadHandler` to achieve this. So I came up with the following.

```
class DirectUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):

    def __init__(self, request=None):
        super().__init__(request)
        self.field_name = None
        self.file_name = None
        self.content_type = None
        self.content_length = None
        self.charset = None
        self.content_type_extra = None
        self.request = request
        self.file = None

    def new_file(self, field_name, file_name, content_type, content_length, charset=None, content_type_extra=None):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.content_type = content_type
        self.content_length = content_length
        self.charset = charset
        self.content_type_extra = content_type_extra
        self.file = open('\\\\10.0.8.5\\filename.ext', 'wb+')

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.file.write(raw_data)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        self.file.seek(0)
        self.file.size = file_size
        return self.file
```

Now the upload is working fine and it is directly writing to the destination. But I have noticed that `file_complete` method is called before the destination file is completely written. All the code execution completed and django view returned that upload is completed. Still the file is growing, and it took few more seconds to complete the writing. Why there is a delay in completing the write process? Why the `file_complete` method is called before the file actually completed writing?